# Convert epoch to the week day without for loop

Tags: python, epoch, dayofweek

With the help of the following code I can define `day of the week` out of epoch:

```
epoch = 4464769126
day = time.strftime('%A', time.localtime(epoch))
print(day)

Friday
```

I have applied it to the column in `df.epoch` with the for loop, but it is time consuming. Any ideas how to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do this using pandas to_datetime function like below

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"epoch": ["4464769126"]})

pd.to_datetime(df["epoch"], unit="s").dt.weekday_name
```